# Is it possible to link Watson Assistant with an Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I want to use a Watson Assistant search skill to search an Oracle Database, I don't know if the search skill is limited to just these and whether I can use any of these for my search?

Box
Salesforce
Microsoft SharePoint Online
Microsoft SharePoint OnPrem
Web Crawl
IBM Cloud Object Storage

Comment: Oracle provides [Oracle Text](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ccapp/index.html) for full-text search.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As you might have seen, the [IBM Watson Assistant search skill](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-skill-add#skill-add-search-skill) is based on reaching out to [Watson Discovery on IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/discovery-data?topic=discovery-data-sources). That cloud service only supports the data source listed in your question.

If you deploy Watson Assistant and Watson Discovery yourself, [there are more options available, including Oracle access via JDBC](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/discovery-data?topic=discovery-data-connector-database-cp4d).